# Eclipse - Yellow highlight and substitution of words with autocomplete

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, highlight

I have a problem with Eclipse in Debian Buster.

Every time I activate autocomplete near a word, the same is highlighted in yellow and, if I confirm completion, it is replaced.

[image: eclipse autocomplete and highlight problem]

In Windows I didn't have this problem; I believe it is some Eclipse setting but I don't know how to disable it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) the default behavior for the Java content assist changed from ***Completion Inserts*** to ***Completion Overwrites***, which can be configured in *Window > **Preferences: Java > Editor > Content Assist*** at the top.

See also my [video showing this new default behavior of the content assist and how the old behavior can be restored](https://youtu.be/CNasSgaeIwo?t=230).

Comment: According to [bug #423642](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=423642), some people actually like this behaviour. I've just spent the last 6 months thinking that Eclipse was broken when editing Java code. Sheesh. (Thanks for your answer, BTW.)

Comment: Oh god thank you thank you, how could this possible be preferable. It gets it wrong over 50% of the time.

Comment: Yeah...wow. Can't really understand how anybody could  consider that the better option - it ALWAYS did the wrong thing for me :(
Thanks, this has increased my quality of life!